# How to transform Kelvin to Celsius in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, geoprocessing, land-surface-temperature

I'm struggling to transform Kelvin to Celsius in Google Earth Engine. I'm working with ERA5 2 meter air monthly average and the output of the code below is in Kelvin.

How can I transform it into Celsius in GEE?

Note: I'm really beginner in GEE.

```
var data = imageCollection.select('minimum_2m_air_temperature');
var time = data.filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31'));
var mean = time.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());
var study_area = mean.clip(area_estudo);
var min_temp = {
  min: 250,
  max: 320,
  palette: [
    '040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
    '0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
    '3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
    'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
    'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003'
  ]
};
Map.addLayer(study_area, min_temp);
```

[image]

Comment: use the formula that convets celsius to kelvin? what stops you to minus the result by 273.15?

Comment: I tried it, using .subtract(273.15). But simply doing it in GEE is not allowed. I don't know if it occurs because I'm using my own shapefile. The examples I saw people normally use LSIB to get the shapefiles, then they can filter in the table.

Comment: You haven't provided a runnable script, so it's difficult for anyone to help you. Like Isaac said, `subtract()` is the way to do this. I'm guessing that you do this subtraction on your image collection instead on an image. Shapefiles shouldn't have anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For applying conversion formula you have to modify slightly your script as [follows](https://code.earthengine.google.com/92eea690288bc665aa135ff6862bf0d2) (I assumed an arbitrary **area_estudo** in Brazil).

```
var area_estudo = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-55.32142411686995, -10.625336326959081],
          [-55.32142411686995, -17.69357055294952],
          [-45.21400224186995, -17.69357055294952],
          [-45.21400224186995, -10.625336326959081]]], null, false);

var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5/MONTHLY");

var study_area = imageCollection.select('minimum_2m_air_temperature')
                          .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31'))
                          .reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
                          .subtract(273.15)
                          .clip(area_estudo);

var min_temp = {
  min: 14, //modified
  max: 22, //modified
  palette: [
    '040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
    '0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
    '3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
    'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
    'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003'
  ]
};
Map.addLayer(study_area, min_temp);
```

After running above script in GEE code editor, you can now visualize that temperatures are expressed in Celsius instead Kelvin degrees.

[image]